# when i select radio button then all radio button is selected. i want only one radio button should be selected

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I am trying to do this.

I have three radio buttons, it is working fine when i use all radio button in a single div but it is not working when i divide all radio button in particular div. i click on it then it is selected but next time when i click on it then still radio button is selected. 
It should be unselected when i click on it.

Please help. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks a lot.
Here's my code so far.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="filter_subdivisions">
<div class="popular_city radio mgnb6 clearfix">
<span class="fltl" style="width:70%;padding-top: 6px;">Delhi Airport</span>
<span class="fltr">
<label class="label_radio" for="radio-01"><input name="sample-radio" id="radio-01" value="1" type="radio" checked />&nbsp;</label>
</span>
</div>
<div class="popular_city radio mgnb6 clearfix">
<span class="fltl" style="width:70%;padding-top: 6px;">Delhi Airport</span>
<span class="fltr">
<label class="label_radio" for="radio-02"><input name="sample-radio" id="radio-02" value="1" type="radio" />&nbsp;</label>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and

```
<script>
var d = document;
var safari = (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('safari') != -1) ? true : false;
var gebtn = function(parEl,child) { return parEl.getElementsByTagName(child); };
onload = function() {
var body = gebtn(d,'body')[0];
body.className = body.className && body.className != '' ? body.className + ' has-js' : 'has-js';

if (!d.getElementById || !d.createTextNode) return;
var ls = gebtn(d,'label');
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
var l = ls[i];
if (l.className.indexOf('label_') == -1) continue;
var inp = gebtn(l,'input')[0];
if (l.className == 'label_radio') {
l.className = (safari && inp.checked == true || inp.checked) ? 'label_radio r_on' : 'label_radio r_off';
l.onclick = turn_radio;
};
};
};
var turn_radio = function() {
var inp = gebtn(this,'input')[0];
if (this.className == 'label_radio r_off' || inp.checked) {
var ls = gebtn(this.parentNode,'label');
for (var i = 0; i < ls.length; i++) {
var l = ls[i];
if (l.className.indexOf('label_radio') == -1)  continue;
l.className = 'label_radio r_off';
};
this.className = 'label_radio r_on';
if (safari) inp.click();
} else {
this.className = 'label_radio r_off';
if (safari) inp.click();
};
};
</script>
```

Comment: change the value of the second one, to value=2, see if that helps

Comment: You should definitely improve this question: what's your problem? I tested your code on Chrome and it works: radio buttons in two different divs, but with the same name, alternate each other.

What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Do you have any idea that how radio button works ? any one radio button will be selected at a time which has same name. you can use checkbox if you wish toggle functionality. So,first Correct/Edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to have `type="radio"` buttons within the same container to make them behave like radio buttons, like as per w3schools example

```
<form>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="male">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female
</form>
```

Comment: This is not true. See, my comment above: it works flawlessly in Chrome.